# Displaying values from multiple MySql database fields together as one

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm doing a project where I have to take in information from a user on a web page and store it in a MySql database. Some of the fields the user has to fill out are his street number, name and suburb and these are separate fields and are stored as separate values in the database.

So, part of the project is to display all of the entries in a table, but combine the info from above (Street no, name, suburb) and display it together in one cell under the heading 'Address' so it shows as full address.

So my question is, what are some ways of doing this?

Everything is working so far and I can display each field individually, so it's just the question of formatting.

Hopefully, you guys can give me a hand,
Cheers!

EDIT: This is how I'm displaying the table right now:

```
 $QueryResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM booking");

    $row = mysql_fetch_row($QueryResult);
    echo "<table width='100%' border='1'>";
    echo "<tr><th>Booking No</th><th>Passanger Name</th><th>Phone</th><th>Unit</th>";
    echo "<th>Street No</th><th>Street Name</th><th>Pick-up Suburb</th><th>Destination Suburb</th>";
    echo "<th>Pick-up Date</th><th>Pickup time</th></tr>";
    $countRows = 0;
    $tweight=0;       
    while($row){

      $countRows++;
      echo "<tr><td>{$row[0]}</td>";
      echo "<td>{$row[1]}</td>";
      echo "<td>{$row[2]}</td>";
      echo "<td>{$row[3]}</td>";
      echo "<td>{$row[4]}</td>";
      echo "<td>{$row[5]}</td>";
      echo "<td>{$row[6]}</td>";
      echo "<td>{$row[7]}</td>";
      echo "<td>{$row[8]}</td>";
      echo "<td>{$row[9]}</td></tr>";




      $row = mysql_fetch_row($QueryResult);
    }
```

How would I use CONCAT in this case?
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the CONCAT function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've put the code up above. If you can have a look. How would I use CONCAT in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `php`:

```
$address = $row[4] . ' ' . $row[5] . ' ' . $row[6];
```

In `mysql`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(street_no, ' ', street_name, ' ', suburb) AS address FROM ...
```

Choose one of them and change this code depending on the variable names you have.